# Awk - print last column or one before last if last is emty

Tags: awk

I want to use `AWK` to get the filename or the last folders name if the string is only a directory.

I have:

```
 awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'
```

to print the last column and:

```
 awk -F '/' '{print $(NF - 1)}
```

to print one column before the last.

How can I make `awk` recognize if the string contains only a directory and no filename and in this case print one column before the last.

My problem is that a directory might look like:

```
./folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

and in this case the last column would be empty. I want `awk` to recognize this and then print `folder3` (so one column before the last one).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use `if` or the `?:` operator for this.

```
awk -F '/' '{print $NF == "" ? $(NF - 1) : $NF}'
```

```
awk -F '/' '{if($NF == "") print $(NF - 1); else print $NF}'
```

Comment: ternary operand  `test ? true : false` is a clever choice.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
awk -F/ '{if (length($NF)) print $NF ; else print $(NF-1) ;}'
```

(I wasn't able to test it though).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU utilities see also:

```
xargs -rd '\n' basename -a --
```

Which on a `list.txt` input like:

```
./folder1/folder2/folder3/
./foo
bar///
/
```

gives:

```
folder3
foo
bar
/
```

`zsh`'s `:t` modifier (from `csh`) gives `""` for `"/"` instead of `"/"`

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${(@)${(f)$(<list.txt)}:t}"
<folder3>
<foo>
<bar>
<>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the shell:

```
$ basename ./folder1/folder2/folder3/
folder3
```

Assigning to a variable, using `basename` with a variable that holds a pathname:

```
filename=$( basename "$pathname" )
```

The `basename` utility is [a standard POSIX utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html).

Comment: thx, my question has been gaining a bit much on the use of `AWK`, using `basename` is much simpler.